# Generalizing the fact that symmetric matrices have only real eigenvalues.

Tags: linear-algebra

We know that if $A$ is a symmetric matrix, then $det (A+xI)$ is a polynomial that only has real roots. Let us assume that we know that this polynomial has non-zero roots. Then, taking $y=\frac{1}{x}$, we deduce that $det (I+yA)$ has only real roots.

Now let $A$ be a symmetric matrix such that each entry is a (possibly infinite) series in $y$ (**EDIT**: with a non-zero constant term). Can $det (I+yA)$ be written as an infinite product of the form $\prod\limits_{i=1}^\infty (1+y b_i)$?

Comment: I don't think every infinite series can be factored that way? Which means you choke at the $1 \times 1$ case, or similarly the diagonal case.

Comment: @DustanLevenstein- The given formula includes the possibility that some factors are repeated, etc. I am just hoping that all "roots" of the determinant are real.

Comment: How about the $1 \times 1$ matrix $A = (y)$?

Comment: @DustanLevenstein- You're right, I should clarify that all the infinite series entries have non-zero constant terms.

Comment: How about $A=(1+y/2)$?

Comment: @DustanLevenstein- You're right. You can put that in as an answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The $1 \times 1$ matrix $A=\begin{pmatrix}1+y/2\end{pmatrix}$ is a counterexample, because
$$\det(I+yA) = 1+y(1+y/2) = 1+y+y^2/2 = \frac{1}{2}( (y+1)^2+1 )$$
has no real roots.